# Change disk geometry Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I've a 32GB MicroSD card detected as 30,6MB. This is the `fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 30,6 MiB, 32096256 bytes, 62688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I think that if I change the disk geometry of the block device, will be able to recover data with testdisk.

So can anybody help me to change disk geometry?

Answer (score 0):

MicroSD cards do not have a real disk geometry.   The MicroSD firmware simply reports a set of values that add up to the total storage space potentially available on the card. Attempting to change the disk geometry makes no sense in this case.

Comment: But Can I change the LBA size for a block device?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?   Are you trying to recover data?

Comment: Yep!! I need to make an SD card image then try to recover the data. I hope data is still there